# How to find CNAME or A details for a site hosted at 1&1 and using CloudFlare name servers?

Tags: web-hosting, dns-hosting, cloudflare, 1and1

I own a domain at 1&1, and recently switched to CloudFlare CDN. I have some subdomains hosted at the minimal web space provided by 1&1.

1&1 domains and subdomains are configured to use CloudFlare name servers from the settings under 1&1 control panel.

When I go to CloudFlare DNS settings, I am not sure what to specify in A or CNAME record for the subdomains hosted by 1&1. I have gone through 1&1 help and settings, but not able to find this information. I used `ns-es.1and1-dns.es` and `1and1.es` as CNAME, but didn't work.

Previously, CloudFlare detected IP for A records, but 1&1 recently switched web servers and the subdomains have stopped working.

Comment: In short, domain and web hosting are both provided by **1&1**, but I am using **CloudFlare** name servers, and can't figure out `CNAME` or `IP` for [_the included subdomain in 1&1 hosting package_](http://help.1and1.com/domains-c36931/transfer-domains-c79823/to-1and1-c37567/add-an-external-domain-that-uses-your-name-server-a713215.html); a problem others have [stumbled over too](https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/pointing-external-domain-to-1and1-webspace/7276)!

Comment: As the OP you can and should [edit your question](http://serverfault.com/posts/774346/edit) when you want to clarify or add details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create a root domain at [**1&1**](http://1and1.com), another domain is created alongside of the format `s12345678.onlinehome.us` or `s12345678.mialojamiento.es` etc. This second domain acts as **`CNAME`** record for the root domain or any subdomains, when using a third party name server.